# Web application does not update when refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, outputcache

I have an ASP .NET Web Application that queries and shows data from a database using ListView Control. When I run the Web App on the browser it works fine, but when I delete or add something in the database, then refresh the browser where the web app is running, its output does not update. How can I make my Web App update when refreshed?

This is the code for the ListView:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="HotfixIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotfixID") %>' /> 
            </td>
            <td>
             <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /> 
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="HotfixIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotfixID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
               <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />  
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" style="">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                    Text="Insert" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Clear" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="HotfixIDTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("HotfixID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" border="0">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server"  style="">
                        <tr runat="server" style="">
                              <th id="Th1" runat="server" align="left">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton0" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="HotfixID" Width="140">Update ID</asp:LinkButton></th>
            <th id="Th2" runat="server">
               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Description" Width="600">Description</asp:LinkButton> </th>
            <th id="Th3" runat="server">
               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Date" Width="100">Date</asp:LinkButton> </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                    Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Cancel" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="HotfixIDTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("HotfixID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="HotfixIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotfixID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SPDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:addremovefinalConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="sp_getupdatesSP_v3" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    onselecting="SPDataSource_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ComboBox1" Name="param" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if its cached or not. Its just a simple ASP .NET Web App created out of Visual Studio.

Comment: Please add you SqlDataSource definition

Comment: Check out the Page Load event, is it firing?

Comment: @user919789: are you binding ListView again after update?

Comment: @user919789: then bind once again your ListView after updating database: ListView1.DataSource=//datasource;
          ListView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as the comments alluded to, clearly the page is being cached.  You can verify this by adding a directive to the top of your page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Location="None" %>
```

That means that your database will be hit for every request, though.  For a better solution I recommend looking into [SQL cache dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

At the time you are Querying the database , you are not refreshing page manually but with server side button that causes postback and refresh the data thus it does not user cache data.

Whereas Afer updating the database you said you are manually refreshing the page , this might be the reason you are getting cached data.

My suggession is to load the page again from server side (rebind the control with new data) after updating database.